# Class created and Public Methods not going over to Test Method

Tags: java, class, methods, public

I created a very simple cash register class and wanted to test it in a separate method.  When I call the methods created in the class over from the test method, there is an error saying that a certain method is undefined in the class where it was created, when that is not the case.  Can somebody please explain why I am getting this error?  Thank you.

class:

```
/**
 * A simulated cash register that tracks the item count and 3 the total
 * amount due.
 */
public class CashRegister {
    private int itemCount;
    private double totalPrice;


    public CashRegister() {
        itemCount = 0;
        totalPrice = 0;
    }


    public void addItem(double price) {
        itemCount++;
        totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return totalPrice;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

    public void clear() {
        itemCount = 0;
        totalPrice = 0;
    }
}
```

testing the class:

```
public class cashRegisterTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        cashRegister register1 = new cashRegister();

        register1.addItem(0.95);
        register1.addItem(2.50);
        System.out.println(register1.getCount());
        System.out.println("Expected: 3");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", register1.getTotal());
        System.out.println("Expected: 5.40");

    }

}
```

Comment: You are declaring a cashregister class which contains absolutely no members, and it declares another nested cashregister class which has some members.  Then, you are trying to test the outer class.  Of course it does not compile, because the outer class has no members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have class within class:

```
 public class cashRegister { /** * A simulated cash register that tracks the item count and 3 the total * amount due. */ 
     public class CashRegister
```

Just delete the `public class CashRegister` and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the first `public class cashRegister {` line and the final `}`.

Comment: No problemo!  We are here to help.